# Why doesn't Windows Server 2012 support .NET framework 4.0?

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-server-2012

I had tried to use my application built on .NET framework 4.0 with Windows Server 2012 but it's not working and according to MSDN, Server 2012 is not supported by .NET Framework 4.0. Why is that? How can I overcome this issue without converting my application to Framework 4.5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.NET v4.5 is kind of updating the runtime of .NET v4.0 with the new one, when you install .NET v4.5 your .NET v4.0 assemblies in the `\Windows\.NET Framework\V4.0.30319` are overwritten with a new set of assemblies. You end up with overwritten assemblies as well as a bunch of new ones (like the new `System.Net.Http` assemblies for example).

See these articles:

[.NET 4.5 is an in-place replacement for .NET 4.0](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40)

[Announcing the release of .NET Framework 4.5 RTM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/15/announcing-the-release-of-net-framework-4-5-rtm-product-and-source-code.aspx)

[Whats new on .Net framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx)

[Application Compatibility in the .NET Framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)

[What's New in .NET Framework 4.5](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/whats-new-in-net-framework-45/240008327)

[Windows Server 2012 blocks Framework 4.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2765375)

http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.de/2012/03/net-45-is-what-to-net-40-replacement-or.html

Comment: Thank you .. Yes they say framework 4.5 supports backward compatibility. But when I read MSDN I found that oleDB connection of framework 4.0 not supported in windows server 2012. :( why is that ? Is MSDN not updated ? see below link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Apparently it’s because the documentation for .net 4.0 didn’t get updated when Server 2012 was released. If you look at the [.net 4.5 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110)), you can see `Server 2012` listed. Since 2012 requires .net 4.5 anyways, it may be impossible for .net 4.0 to support 2012 because you can’t install 4.0 on 2012 anyways. So it might make sense that way.

Comment: What about apps requiring the **.net 4.0 Client Profile**?

Comment: I am having the same issue, and I am still unable to resolve it :(. Can any one please see my [question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/876618/unable-to-run-web-api-on-servers-localhost)