# Lightswitch 2011 and Windows Server 2012 Standard edition

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, windows-server-2012

Can be Lightswitch 2011 application deployed on windows server 2012 standard edition, please?

In my opinion, 
officially supported .NET framework for Lightswitch 2011 (and also 2012) is only 4.0 version ([see this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2013/01/23/enabling-net-framework-4-5-on-lightswitch-server-projects.aspx)). And .NET Framework 4.0 is not supported on Windows Server 2012 ([from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). So Lightswitch 2011(and 2012) is not officially supported on Windows Server 2012. Right?

Hovewer, on first link is guide, how enable .NET framework 4.5, but only for Lightswitch 2012.

Does anyone have experience with this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET 4.5 Supposedly provides 100% backwards compatibility, meaning it should support your lightswitch 11 app. Have you read this? [Why doesn't Windows Server 2012 support .NET framework 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684541/why-doesnt-windows-server-2012-support-net-framework-4-0)

The .NET 4.5 Works side by side with earlier frameworks but it *replaces* .NET 4.0. Win Server 2012 (with 4.5 installed) will not allow you to install an earlier version of the framework.

Beth Massi's article is about taking advantage of new additions on .NET 4.5. Lightswitch v2 was targeted at .NET 4.0 to exculde the *necessity* of having 4.5 to run it.

> "Additionally the LightSwitch runtime takes no **dependency** on .NET 4.5, just 4.0. "

This might also be interesting: [Differences between .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 in High level in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492647/differences-between-net-4-0-and-net-4-5-in-high-level-in-net)

This has Microsoft's compatibility message for the .NET 4.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx and probably is the best link to answer your question. It may also help if you decide to migrate to 2012/4.5

Comment: Have you tried deploying your app in a 2012 server? If you need more clarification, please let me know. And if this answers your questions, please mark as answer.

Comment: I will try deploy on 2012 server next week.

Comment: I have successfully deployed the Lightswitch application on the Windows Server 2012 without any problem.