# Will application based on .NET FW 4.0 work on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, .net-framework-version

I'm a little bit confused about .NET framework versions and its compatibility with operating system. Please help.

I plan to upgrade my application to .NET 4.x.
My application must support a variety of operating systems: XP, Windows Server 2003, 2008 (and R2) , 2012 (and R2), Windows 7.x and Windows 8.x.

I'd prefer to release one kit only - which means build the application with one specific .NET framework. The big question is which one?

I know that .NET 4.0 supports from XP to Windows Server 2008 R2 but does not support WS 2012.
I know that .NET 4.5.1 supports WS 2012 and R2.

I'm wondering if what happens if I use my application with FW 4.0 and then try to install it on Windows Server 2012 R2: will it work (backward compatibility?) or not?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate for ServerFault and would get a better response there.

Comment: Why? It's a question for developers I think

Comment: Fair enough, just thought you might get a better response on ServerFault

Answer (score 0):

Apparently **.NET 4.5** binary files  replace **.NET 4.0**  ones with `100% backwards compatibility` according to [this from Rick Strahl's](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40) and [this from Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684541/why-doesnt-windows-server-2012-support-net-framework-4-0).

Also when you install your program on XP with **.NET 4.0**, make sure it's **XP SP3** because that's the youngest version 'officially' supported.

However, just in case that you happen to want it on **SP2**, there is [some trick](http://nowfromhome.com/net-40-on-windows-xp-sp2/) you can force **.NET 4.0** to be installed on **XP SP2**.