# Application pool for .NET 4.0 does not appear when I have .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, application-pool

I have installed .NET 4.5 but my project uses .NET 4.

My OS is Microsoft server 2012 R2. I can't re-install .NET 4 as the OS has already in-built .NET 4.
[image]
As you can see, I can only see .NET 4.5 in IIS (6.5).

I've runned `aspnet_regiis.exe -ir` and got positive result but application pools still does not show it.

[image]

How can I make .NET 4.0 application pool appear on a machine with .NET 4.5?

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684541/why-doesnt-windows-server-2012-support-net-framework-4-0

Comment: Learn via Google why .NET Framework 4.5 is an in-place upgrade of 4.0, then you should be able to answer this question on your own.

Comment: Thank you for both of you! I've got the answer.