# .NET header in response from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I host an application on Windows Server machine where the 4.7.1 version of .NET Framework is installed. 
But while sending request to the server in response I got header

```
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
```

I'm a bit confused, what about exactly tells this header? Is possible to improve this version to version instaled on server?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not which version is installed on your system, it tells which version your application is built on. If you want to remove this header add this config <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/14684856/3953479

Comment: @Ipsit Guar it does not seem to be true, because my application is built in .NET Framework 4.6.2. I found it in solution properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is CLR (common language runtime) version, as reported by [Environment.Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version(v=vs.110).aspx):

> For the .NET Framework Versions 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, and 4.5.2, the
>   Environment.Version property returns a Version object whose string
>   representation has the form 4.0.30319.xxxxx. For the .NET Framework
>   4.6, its point releases, and the .NET Framework 4.7, it has the form 4.0.30319.42000.

So for all .NET 4+ versions (including 4.7.1 you are running), CLR version major-minor-build parts are 4.0.30319, only revision differs (which is not displayed in X-AspNet-Version header).

I'm not aware of a way to "improve" this header to include revision number, though I also don't see much reason to do that (or include that header in response at all).